# Batch script check array variable always goes to ELSE statement

Tags: arrays, batch-file, if-statement

I have a batch script which asks the user to input a server. Then it checks if it is from an array, where the servers require 3 password to login. Otherwise 2 passwords are needed. I check this in a for loop but always end up going to the else statement. Why? Here is the code:

```
@echo off
set  arrayserver[0]=server1
set  arrayserver[1]=server2
set  arrayserver[2]=server3
set  arrayserver[3]=server4
set  arrayserver[4]=server5
set  arrayserver[5]=server6
set  arrayserver[6]=server7
set  arrayserver[7]=server8
set  arrayserver[8]=server9
set  arrayserver[9]=server10
set arrayserver[10]=server11
set arrayserver[11]=server12
set arrayserver[12]=server13
set arrayserver[13]=server14
set arrayserver[14]=server15
set arrayserver[15]=server16
set arrayserver[16]=server17
set arrayserver[17]=server18
set arrayserver[18]=server19
set arrayserver[19]=server20
set arrayserver[20]=server21
set arrayserver[21]=server22
set arrayserver[22]=server23
set arrayserver[23]=server24
set arrayserver[24]=server25
set arrayserver[25]=server26
set arrayserver[26]=server27
set user2=user2
set user3=user3
set i=0
set /p server=Enter server: 
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%s in ('set arrayserver[') do (
if "%server%" == "%%s" (
    goto breakit
) else (
    goto breakit2
))

:breakit
echo You will be prompted for 3 passwords:
echo -pass1
echo -pass2
echo -Oracle user
echo ssh -t -A %user2%@hop2 ssh -t -A %EDSUSER%@%server% su - oracle > C:\Temp\linkche.txt
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Putty\putty.exe" -ssh -A -t %USER%@hop1 -m C:\Temp\linkche.txt
del C:\Temp\linkche.txt
goto :oef

:breakit2
echo You will be prompted for 2 passwords:
echo -pass1
echo -Oracle user
echo ssh -t -A %user2%@hop2 ssh -A oracle@%server% > C:\Temp\linkche.txt
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Putty\putty.exe" -ssh -A -t %USER%@hop1 -m C:\Temp\linkche.txt
del C:\Temp\linkche.txt
goto :oef
```

Comment: I've edited my answer and added a fix proposal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's simple. You are in a loop but after checking the first server you are entering the ELSE case. **So you are jumping out of the loop after the first iteration**. You can verify this by entering `server1`. In this case the IF case is executed. Further, `GOTO :oef` makes no sense. I suppose you want to do `GOTO :EOF`. While EOF means **EndOfFile**, OEF means nothing (or possibly OfEndFile? :D).

To fix your problem you should modify your loop like this:

```
...
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%s in ('set arrayserver[') do (
    if "%server%" == "%%s" (
        goto breakit
    )
)
goto breakit2
...
```

Now you will jump to `breakit` if the input is between server1 and server27 or to `breakit2` otherwise. And don't forget to replace oef with eof.

Comment: It is :eof, of course :D Thanks for the answer. I was stuck with a wrong logic behind my script.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to iterate over the array elements. If you define the array with the server values *as subscripts* with any value in the element (instead of numeric subscripts with the server in the value), then you may directly test if such server exist via a `if defined arrayserver[%server%] ...` command. I also use  a simpler way to define the array.

```
@echo off

rem Define the server array with the server *in the subscript*; the assigned value does NOT matter
for %%a in (server1  server2  server3  server4  server5  server6  server7  server8  server9  server10
            server11 server12 server13 server14 server15 server16 server17 server18 server19 server20
            server21 server22 server23 server24 server25 server26 server27) do (
   set  arrayserver[%%a]=3
)

set user2=user2
set user3=user3
set /p server=Enter server: 

if not defined arrayserver[%server%] goto passwords-2

:passwords-3
echo You will be prompted for 3 passwords:
echo -pass1
echo -pass2
echo -Oracle user
echo ssh -t -A %user2%@hop2 ssh -t -A %EDSUSER%@%server% su - oracle > C:\Temp\linkche.txt
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Putty\putty.exe" -ssh -A -t %USER%@hop1 -m C:\Temp\linkche.txt
del C:\Temp\linkche.txt
goto :eof

:passwords-2
echo You will be prompted for 2 passwords:
echo -pass1
echo -Oracle user
echo ssh -t -A %user2%@hop2 ssh -A oracle@%server% > C:\Temp\linkche.txt
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Putty\putty.exe" -ssh -A -t %USER%@hop1 -m C:\Temp\linkche.txt
del C:\Temp\linkche.txt
goto :eof
```

You may even define array elements with different values for 2 and 3 passwords, and then directly use their values to go to the appropriate section with *no* `if` command!

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Servers with 3 passwords:
for %%a in (server1 server2 server27) do set arrayserver[%%a]=3

rem Servers with 2 passwords:
for %%a in (serverA serverB serverZ) do set arrayserver[%%a]=2

set /p server=Enter server: 
goto passwords-!arrayserver[%server%]!
```

For further info about array management in Batch files, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990).